# Add event to calendar xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, eventkit

I have a basic app with a list view with manualy added cells.

How would i make it so that when a cell is clicked , a specific date is added to the iphone calendar?

Info - using latest xcode with storyboards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a delegate for you list view that response to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. By `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can catch the click to your cell.
Then, use `EKEventStore` class to access your calendar. Your appointment is represented by an `EKEvent`.

**EDIT**

For more information you should consult the [Introduction to Calendars and Reminders](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765), [Event Kit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html), and [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

This is the general approach, for a more detailed description you should tell, what your issues are and what did you try. Nobody at SO will write the program for you.

Comment: do you have a detailed example of this?